# Check if atleast form data is not empty in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a search function in laravel 5.6
I have multiple form fields. And everything is fine with search queries. 
And with out empty form data it returns all datas from db.
I want to check if atleast a field is not empty to pass queries else i want to return error. How can i do that in Laravel. Thanks in advance

```
if ($request->all() != '') {
            // Search for  nursery based on their freeword.
            if (!empty($request->input('description'))) {
                $nursery->Where('description',  'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('description') . '%');
                $nursery->orWhere('name',  'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('description') . '%');
}
```

Comment: what parameter you passing :  description and  name ...any other fileds ?

Comment: are you sending json response or direct data to blade view ?

Comment: locations, price, age from different columns

Comment: i am sending json response

Answer (score 0):

this will validate your required inputs and gives error if any missing , else it will search

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function search(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'locations' => 'required',
                'price'=>'required',
                'age'=>'required',
                'description'=>'required'
            ]
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $response=array('status'=>'error','errors'=>implode(',', $validator->errors()->all()));
            return response()->json($response, 400);
        }else{
             // your code here ...
            $nursery->Where('description',  'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('description') . '%');
            $nursery->orWhere('name',  'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('description') . '%');
            // your code here ...
            return response()->json(['status'=>'success','result'=>$result],200);
        }

}
```

Comment: @naVin Shrestha , please try the above code and upvote if it is working

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't use validation because what i am doing is i am making search queries even a field is entered. So i need to check whether there is at least single form data entered or if there is not a single value i want to throw error.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create custom request by following [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests). You can define the rules.
2. You can use `validation` method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53537852/3851720)
3. You can use `$request->has('key')` method or `empty($request->all())` function to check.
4. You can use `$value = $request->input('key', 'default value');` to check if value or set default value to variable.
5. You can use `when` method like below

See Example :

```
$categoryId = $request->input('category_id', null);
$query = Product::query();
$query->when($categoryId, function ($q) use ($categoryId) {

    return $q->where('category_id', $categoryId);

});

$query->get();
```